# Про html и javascript

Tags: javascript

У меня alert, prompt и прочие функции нормально работают в файле script.js, но вот вызов элементов и подобные штуки не работают.

```
<script>
     document.body.children[0].style.color = "red";
</script>
```

Причем в самом HTML с помощью тега скрипта они работают... Это связано с тем, что HTML элементы нужно вызвать в HTML файле, или я что-то не правильно делаю?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Comment: добавил, благодарю за помощь

Comment: Потому что во время работы скрипта, элементов еще может не быть на странице. Посмотрите на событие `onload`, например.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что скрипт работает прежде, чем открывает страницу? А как делать, чтобы скрипт работал после загрузки страницы? Я только начал учить javascript, пока читаю теорию и играю с элементами, прошу относиться с пониманием))

Comment: Я ведь уже ответил. Почитайте про события загрузки, в частность событие `onload`.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded